# is it okay to torrent without an anti-virus? will it affect my windows 7 if I catch Malware?

Tags: bittorrent, malware

Should I worry about viruses when I torrent on Ubuntu? what can I do to prevent it? Do I need to go to such lengths?

I don't want to torrent something and find out there is a dormant virus in there ready to strike when I boot up my Windows, or just plain and simply affect Ubuntu.

Comment: Related question with very relevant answers: [Do I need to have 'antivirus software' installed?](/q/10373)

Answer (score 3):

Your Ubuntu is pretty safe from all viruses you catch.

**As long as you don't make them**, partitions do not interfere with each other, so your Windows should be safe if you don't copy infected file from  Ubuntu to Windows.
[I'm not the only one who thinks so.](https://superuser.com/questions/51547/can-a-virus-enter-via-ubuntu-and-affect-windows-in-dual-boot) Moreover, you do have Windows anti-virus, don't you?

If you want to pass a file from Ubuntu to Windows, you can use something like [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/) to scan it.

Nevertheless, saying goes, better safe then sorry. Check [Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Antivirus) for a list of reasons, why linux in general is pretty safe from viruses and optional anti-virus programs.

Comment: Technically Linux/Ubuntu is not much safer from malware than Windows. It's just that there are very few viruses that target Linux/Ubuntu desktop systems – so few that most system operators don't bother with anti-virus software.

Comment: @David Foerster But most servers run Linux. Why attack desktops, when knocking out servers could paralyse regions if not continents?

Comment: Yes, but how is that relevant to the vulnerability of desktop systems (which OP is asking about btw)?

Comment: Yes, it is, because Ubuntu server and Ubuntu Desktop are basically same OS with different bells.

Comment: OS and OS subsystem vulnerabilities are relatively rare and subsequently rarely the attack vector for malware. Most malware spreads through vulnerabilities in (server) applications and this is where server and desktop systems differ greatly, primarily because desktop systems don't expose any services to the internet.

Comment: Meaning desktops are safer by default

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, you shouldn't have to worry.

Torrenting a file is simply downloading the exact same file in small chunks from multiple sources. From the [Torrent file wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torrent_file)

> In the BitTorrent file distribution system, a torrent file is a
>   computer file that contains metadata about files and folders to be
>   distributed, and usually also a list of the network locations of
>   trackers, which are computers that help participants in the system
>   find each other and form efficient distribution groups called swarms.

And from the [BitTorrent wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent):

> BitTorrent is a protocol for the practice of peer-to-peer file sharing
>   that is used to distribute large amounts of data over the Internet.

Basically, you get the `.torrent` file from the server. That provides your torrent client (Transmission by default in Ubuntu - you may use some else like [μTorrent](http://www.utorrent.com) on Windows) with the information necessary to download the file.

As for what's *in* the `.torrent` file - From the BitTorrent wikipedia page:

> Torrent files have an "announce" section, which specifies the URL of
>   the tracker, and an "info" section, containing (suggested) names for
>   the files, their lengths, the piece length used, and a SHA-1 hash code
>   for each piece, all of which are used by clients to verify the
>   integrity of the data they receive.

That is what protects you against viruses. The only way you would get a virus is if the *official* ISO *from Canonical/Ubuntu* was infected - something very unlikely. Plus, you're simply *downloading* the file. You're not actually doing anything with it.

So, the answer to your question is that it is ***extremely*** unlikely (if not entirely impossible) that you will get a virus from torrenting the ISO. The most likely way you'd get a virus while downloading the ISO is if you use an off-brand torrent application that has a virus embedded in the installer.

Comment: I guess he meant downloading torrents from darker sides of the net for films/games/etc.

Comment: @julka Good point - mis-read his question and thought he was asking about catching a virus by downloading the Ubuntu ISO on Windows. Oops!

Comment: @julka: Downloading is still safe as long as there are no (known) vulnerabilities in the torrent client. What happens with the payload after the download is another thing.